# How to autoincrement ID value when there are 2 primary keys in an SQL table?

Tags: sql, database-design

I am making a social media app that includes posts and comments, therefore I created `Post` and `Comment` tables. `Comment` is a weak entity, so that it has 2 primary keys: `comment_id` and `post_id`.

When creating a comment on a post, `comment_id` always appears as `None`. How can I assign auto incremented values to `comment_id`?

```
CREATE TABLE Post(
    post_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(100),
    content TEXT,
    date DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES NonAdmin(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Comment (
    comment_id INTEGER,
    post_id INTEGER,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    content TEXT,
    date DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (comment_id, post_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES NonAdmin(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES Post(post_id)
);
```

Comment: A table can never have more than one primary key. However. a primary key can consist of several columns.

Comment: Its much easier to go with unique comment-IDs and add post_id as parent/child-relation only via foreign keys. Even if you would add autoincrement to comment-ID it won't restart with 0/1 again on every post-ID but would be basically a unique number over the whole table. If you want to achive an ID which restarts with every post-ID you would basically need to implement that in your software on your own. But that just adds complexity without any reason.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) And that is not an SQL error. Debug one system layer at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You should have only `comment_id` as your primary key if you want to have normalized table. If you want to assign the same comment to many posts, then you should create 3rd table with the proper relations. However, I don't see the reason why the same comment should be attached to the different posts.

```
CREATE TABLE Comment (
    comment_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    post_id INTEGER,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    content TEXT,
    date DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES NonAdmin(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES Post(post_id)
);
```

Comment: I don't want to add the same comment in different posts. If I have 2 posts with one comment in each of them, both comments should have a `comment_id` of 1, but different `post_id`'s. That's why I make both `comment_id` and `post_id` primary key in the `Comment` table.

Comment: It's easier to have unique ids in comment table. Why do you want to have the same ID for different comment? Please elaborate on your reasoning.